# How to use Azure AD only for authentication like an API call without using a middleware in .NET Core

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an existing application which has an auth service generating a JWT token validating username and password in the application database. While building the claims we are generating permissions based on user role mapping within the database.

As of now, we don't want to depend on IT to create roles for the user that are specific to our application, so we intend to use Azure AD only for authentication but not for authorization.

We are planning to use existing JWT token builder to build the token once AD authentication is successful. Please suggest how to use AD authentication as an API call to validate the user by username and password and on success we can generate our own JWT token.

Everywhere I am finding solution to basically on behalf of flow which I feel is not according to my expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure AD to finish your authentication flow, and once you get back success result and JWT from AD, then you can retrieve the user details via `claims` in the token, then perform `authorize` logic as per your application database roles, then prepare a new JWT token using `JwtSecurityToken` class of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt. You can fill in the role name(s) into claims section in this new token. This token can henceforth be used by rest of your app to perform RBAC logic.

Comment: This solution solves half of my problem and will have an impact on client-side application. That's the reason my question is asking a way to validate Azure AD user by his username and password by an API call inside the Auth service. If I have such option in Azure AD to make an API call to validate user and based on success return, I will generate a new JWT token by including role related permission from my inhouse db.

Comment: If your auth service needs to do non interactive auth, then you could get the access token via calling the API, see the answer in https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/413244/authenticate-azure-rest-api-using-username-and-pas.html

Comment: We need like an endpoint from Azure AD where we can send username and password and user gets validated from Azure AD. This is what I am exactly looking for

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication 
I tried this MSAL library but here we are getting 0 Accounts as a response of GetAccountsAsync method.  Now I am not sure why we are getting 0 accounts always. Is it related to configuring my app registration or something related to code this I don't know. Need help here.

Comment: This Microsoft.Identity.Client library solved my problem please find below the referenced Git code snippet.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication